# Command runs in Ubuntu terminal but not in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ubuntu terminal and vscode terminal behave differently, at least for the following command.
Why and how can I fix it?

```sh
paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/phone-outgoing-calling.oga
```

In Ubuntu terminal makes a sound.

In vscode terminal gives the following error:

```sh
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: Good question, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/etc/pulse/client.conf` contains:

```
; autospawn = yes
```

If this, is already the case, try purging and reinstalling

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install pulseaudio
```

Comment: I did both but the same issue persists.

Comment: Which additional info do you get when running it in debug mode?